# Javascript function wont stop calling it self again and again

Tags: javascript

I have a java script function that will be triggered by the onclick event on the publish button. The function then checks for media and if the condition is true it will trigger another alertify function which will alert the user to make a selection OK or Cancel, and if clicked on OK, it will use jquery to make the post request with the click function. And if clicked Cancel it will not do anything. If there is a media on this page then the alertify will not show up at all, then it will check for the media. The problem is with the videos. I am uploading the videos on youtube so if i do not wait untill i see the response from youtube and make the post request then my videos is lost.

The whole purpose of this question is to make the script wait and check again and again until i see the video and then programmatically make the post request.

This is My buttons:

```
<style>
    #spinner {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: url(assets/images/loadermain.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    }
</style>
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.2/build/css/alertify.min.css"/>

<button id="publish_job" class="btn btn-success radius" type="submit" name="jobupdate"
onclick="videomsg();">

<div id="spinner"></div>
```

This is my script

```
<script>
    var confirmOpt = true;

    function videomsg() {

        if (confirmOpt && ($(".dz-filename").length ==0)) { //The alert will only be shown if there is no video or no image. If either one exists it will not execute.
            event.preventDefault();
            alertify.confirm('Aloovi', '', function () {
                confirmOpt = false;
                $("#publish_job").click();
                $('#spinner').show();
            }, function () {}).set({
                transition: 'zoom',
                message: 'It is highly recommended to add a photo and/or video describing your project in order to allow the service pro to give a more accurate bid.'
            }).set('labels', {
                ok: 'Publish Now',
                cancel: 'Go Back'
            }).show();
        } else if($(".dz-preview").length >0){
            $('#spinner').show();
            event.preventDefault();

            var waitForEl = function (selector, callback) {
                if (jQuery(selector).length) {
                    callback();
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        waitForEl(selector, callback);
                    }, 100);
                }
            };

            if ($(".dz-file-preview").length > 0) {
                console.log('uploading video ....');
                var selector = ".embed-responsive"
                waitForEl(selector, function () {
                    // work the magic
                    console.log('found it submit with vid');
                    $("#publish_job").click();

                });
            } else {
                console.log('sumbit with nv only pic')
                $("#publish_job").click();
            }
            //----------
        }
        else{
            console.log('submitting the job without videos and picture');
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.2/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
```

I have already tried a lot of different solution found on stack overflow like Set Interval and clear Interval, but they are not the ideal solution for this application and set interval and clear interval is not supported in opera mini.

while I run this script i get this on console log:

```
uploading video ....
VM33958:41 found it submit with vid
VM33958:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
    at videomsg (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:24:19)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.php?page=postajob:1)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at n.fn.init.n.fn.(/anonymous function) [as click] (http://aloovi.test/assets/js/jquery.min.js:4:15584)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:42:39)
    at waitForEl (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:28:21)
```

I just tried passing the event on the function

> `onclick="videomsg(event);"`

and changed the function defination to

> `function videomsg(ev) {....`
>   and changed the 
>   `event.preventDefault(); to ev.preventDefault();`
>   inside the function defination and i have the following output on the console

```
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
VM34644:36 uploading video ....
VM34644:40 found it submit with vid
```

But

> `$("#publish_job").click();`
>   does not execute at all

Comment: This looks questionable...you are calling the click event of a button inside the that buttons click event handler function. --> $("#publish_job").click();

Comment: @RossBush can you elaborate more

Comment: You seem to be orchestrating an async pattern inside of an event handler that can conditionally call upon itself. So if things go wrong, a flag not set as expected, then I could see where you might end up with repeated calls.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a return after event.preventDefault()?

Comment: is that the reason it is giving this error VM33958:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Comment: I don't think event is defined within that scope.

Comment: so how should i pass the event so that i will be prevented

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192332/discussion-between-kiran-bhattarai-and-ross-bush).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding

> `id="descfrm"`
>   to my form and

```
if ($(".dz-file-preview").length > 0) {
                console.log('uploading video ....');
                var selector = ".embed-responsive"
                waitForEl(selector, function () {
                    // work the magic
                    console.log('found it submit with vid');
                    var additionalinput = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "jobupdate");
                    $('#descfrm').append(additionalinput).submit();

                });
            } else {
                console.log('sumbit with nv only pic')
                var additionalinput = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "jobupdate");
                $('#descfrm').append(additionalinput).submit();
            }
```

If there is a better solution than this please do post your answer, I would really appreciate a clean code with a detail explanation. Thank you Stack overflow community.